# Swift - How to build iOS user interface dynamically from XML code?

Tags: ios, swift, xml, dynamic, xml-parsing

I have the following sample xml code which my app receives. My job is to create certain UI elements such as textfields and labels based on this xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Form> 
    <Group description="Alap" name="GEN"> 
            <Field name="CUSNUM" type="F" length="0" lines="1" constraint="" mcHandler="" readOnly="false" hidden="false" mandatory="true" label="Üzletkód" width="2"/> 
            <Field name="CUSTOMERNAME" type="F"  length="0" readOnly ="false" label="Üzlet neve" width="2"/> 
            <Field name="COMPANYNAME" type="F" length="0" readOnly ="false" label="Cég neve" width="2"/> 
            <Field name="ZIPCODE" type="F" length="0" readOnly ="false" label="Irányítószám" width="2"/> 
            <Field name="CITY" type="F" length="0" readOnly ="false" label="Település" width="2"/> 
            <Field name="ADDRESS" type="F" length="0" readOnly ="false" label="Cím" width="2"/> 
    </Group>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically about XML parsing, if you don't mind using an external library, you could take a look at [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper).

The model classes to map your XML will be:

```
class Form: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var group: Group?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        group <- map["Group"]
    }
}

class Group: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var fields: [Field]?
    var description: String?
    var name: String?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        fields <- map["Field"]
        description <- map.attributes["description"]
        name <- map.attributes["name"]
    }
}

class Field: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var name: String?
    var type: String?
    var length: Int?
    var lines: Int?
    var constraint: String?
    var mcHandler: String?
    var readOnly: Bool?
    var hidden: Bool?
    var mandatory: Bool?
    var label: String?
    var width: Int?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {

    }

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        name <- map.attributes["name"]
        type <- map.attributes["type"]
        length <- map.attributes["length"]
        lines <- map.attributes["lines"]
        constraint <- map.attributes["constraint"]
        mcHandler <- map.attributes["mcHandler"]
        readOnly <- map.attributes["readOnly"]
        hidden <- map.attributes["hidden"]
        mandatory <- map.attributes["mandatory"]
        label <- map.attributes["label"]
        width <- map.attributes["width"]
    }
}
```

And you can map your XML string by using `XMLMapper` like:

```
let form = XMLMapper<Form>().map(XMLString: xmlString)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to parse the XML using [XMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparser).

You then walk through the resulting data structure and manually create the `UILabel`s and possibly `UIView`s per Group.

Finally you add each UI element above to the current `UIView`.

If you're adding a `UIView` per Group, you of course need to make that the current `UIView`. And when you reach the end of the Fiels in a group, you need to pop back to the previous `UIView` (i.e., the `superview` of the current `UIView`).

The XML does not define where exactly you need to place the Fields and Groups. This is something that should be defined by the requirements/wishes of the party asking you to make this. I suggest you define top/bottom/left/right margins, plus a horizontal and vertical margin between labels and group views.

You could use iOS auto-layout, but this will add code. To decide, have a look how complex these UIs can become **in realistic scenarios** and how much size flexibility you need. Don't write 'generic' stuff that's not necessary; you'd rather focus on keeping code simple & understandable.

Comment: thanks, there's a lot of xml parsers on github too, do you recommend using apple's xml parser or something else from github?

Comment: @MartonZeisler Personally I hold of adding external stuff as long as possible, to keep things simple and limit dependencies. In this case Apple's implementation if probably fast/good enough or better.